# Silverlight and Session

Tags: silverlight, web-services, session

I have a silverlight web application that maybe open for days.  It uses a legacy web service that uses session...

How can I keep the session of the web service alive as long as the Silverlight appication is alive....

Good times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in control of both the Silverlight Client and the Webservice, you could add a Keep-Alive Method to the Service and periodically call it via Timer from the Silverlight Client. It's definitely not pretty though. In my opinion it would be better to find a way to work out a solution that does not require to maintain session state (or state in general) within the service.

Comment: +1 You can use a KeepAlive for this. You just need to make sure your timer is set to less than the session limit (20 minutes by default, I think).